# Only one consumer per RabbitMQ queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ with help of this php library https://github.com/jakubkulhan/bunny, right now my code work in the following manner: every queue has separate class for adding new messages to queue and separate queue worker, for example: SmsQueue and SmsWorker. I run queue worker 
(for example SmsWorker) from cron, the thing is that I want to run the worker only if it's not running already. I thought that RabbitMQ has some way to see if there are currently active consumers of queue, but I could not find it. What is the solution here and am I doing it right?

P.S. I just have started using RabbitMQ and don't know much about it so sorry if it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that RabbitMQ has some way to see if there are currently active consumers of queue,

not directly, no.

you may be able to find a way to query for this in the HTTP API of the management tool, but I wouldn't do that. the amount of time in between the query running and you starting your code could allow for more than one app instance to be created.

Instead, I would look at two options:

1) request exclusive access to the queue, for the consumer (not sure about your library, but it's part of the AMQP spec: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume.exclusive)

2) use a mutex in your application, to make sure your application is only running once

Alternatively, set up your consumer app so that you only ever have one instance of it and it's always running. If you are not dynamically starting new instances, there will never be more than one instance.